# Rails 6 Parallel Tests fail with improbable ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

When running tests on our newly upgraded Rails 6.0.2.1, and am trying the new parallel testing feature.

When run with parallelism of anything but 1, I get: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 61, expected 1)`

Tests pass when run with `PARALLEL_WORKERS=1`, so I believe my test suite is ok, and this is an issue with the runner, or my configuration of it.

Every single test has the same error, below is one example:

```
Error:
NotificationChannels::AmazonSQSTest#test_send_open_notification:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 61, expected 1)

rails test test/models/notification_channels/amazon_sqs_test.rb:32
```

Line 32 is the test definition itself, nothing unusual: `test "send open notification" do`. We also have tests in the form of `def test_foo` that are failing in the same manner.

The various numbered test databases appear to have been created and populated as I'd expect.

I'm at a loss at what to look at.

Versions of stuff:

- Rails 6.0.2.1
- minitest 5.10.3
- Ruby 2.6.5

Comment: [mre] please. This is not a useful question without an MRE.

Comment: More importantly for you its not an answerable question. How do you expect anybody to be able to answer this without seeing the test or the object under test? You're really only giving us a theory that PARALLEL_WORKERS is the cause but we can't eliminate anything.